# WebP format support with backward compatibility (support in IE, Safari)

Tags: media-library, dianoga

I am using Dianoga module (Thanks to Kam Figy) to optimize the images. At present looking to enable *WebP* format with backward compatibility (serving default image format for un-supported browsers)

Latest Dianoga version supports *WebP* format (Thanks to Anton). Everything works fine after following the steps in the [documentation](https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga#how-to-enable-webp-support).

**Issue**: If first request comes from *WebP* supported browser, then optimization runs for *WebP* format, and cached under Media Cache folder. But subsequent requests from non-supported browsers are failing.

**Analysis:** There is no issue with Diagona module. When the second request comes from non-supported browser, it is matching the Item and Key, serving the image directly from cache, which is in *WebP* format.

Is there anyway to differentiate the requests with extension, so that supported image formats are served for the browsers.

In the ***.ini*** file already there is an entry for extension.

[image]

Can we add one more parameter under protectedMediaQueryParameters or any other way to differentiate the media request by extension? Is it the recommended approach?

```
   <protectedMediaQueryParameters>
      <parameter description="width" name="w"/>
      <parameter description="height" name="h"/>
      <parameter description="max width" name="mw"/>
      <parameter description="max height" name="mh"/>
      <parameter description="scale" name="sc"/>
      <parameter description="allow stretch" name="as"/>
      <parameter description="background color" name="bc"/>
      <parameter description="database name" name="db"/>
      <parameter description="ignore aspect ratio" name="iar"/>
      <parameter description="language code" name="la"/>
      <parameter description="thumbnail" name="thn"/>
      <parameter description="version number" name="vs"/>
      <parameter description="content database" name="sc_content"/>
      <parameter description="content language name" name="sc_lang"/>
      <parameter description="context site" name="sc_site"/>
      <parameter description="grayscale filter" name="gray"/>
      <parameter description="media revision" name="rev"/>
      <parameter description="image extension" name="extension"/>
    </protectedMediaQueryParameters>
```

Sitecore version: **8.2 Update 5 (170728)**
Dianoga version: **4.0.0**

Comment: yes, your idea is correct. You can add '<parameter description="image extension" name="extension"/>' to the list of protected media queries parameters and it will fix the issue.

Comment: Added it as fix: https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga/pull/44

Comment: Thanks Anton, would you mind adding it as an answer, so i can mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your idea is correct. Problem is that Sitecore media request protection removes extra parameter `extension` that is required for Dianoga WebP to work. After adding `extension` to protected media query parameters:

```
<parameter description="image extension" name="extension"/>
```

everything should work as expected.
Pull request to Dianoga that fixes this issue [was added](https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga/pull/44).

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to a patch config which fixed it for me:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <mediaLibrary>
      <requestProtection>
        <customMediaQueryParameters>
          <parameter description="file extension" name="extension">
          </parameter>
        </customMediaQueryParameters>
      </requestProtection>
    </mediaLibrary>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

It's probably more idiomatic to add to `customMediaQueryParameters` than `protectedMediaQueryParameters`. This is the conditional check in the MediaOptions class to show it works the same way:

```
if (!MediaOptions.KnownOptions.ContainsKey(key) && (!MediaManager.Config.RequestProtection.Enabled || MediaManager.Config.RequestProtection.QueryParametersToProtect.Contains(key) || MediaManager.Config.RequestProtection.CustomQueryParameters.Contains(key)))
{
    stringList.Add(key);
}
```